# Preprocessor macro that inserts another preprocessor macro

Tags: logging, macros, c-preprocessor

Is there a way to insert preprocessor macro using another preprocessor macro?

Can I do something like, for instance

```
    #define INSERT_MACRO(x) {#ifdef MYFLAG x; #endif}
```

so that when I write

```
    INSERT_MACRO(foo(););
```

it is converted to

```
    #ifdef MYFLAG
    foo();
    #endif
```

? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use another preprocessor directive in define. 
Instead you may consider,

```
#ifdef MYFLAG
#define INSERT_MACRO(x) x;
#else
#define INSERT_MACRO(x) 
#endif
```